# paid membership pro blank CSV file

Tags: wordpress

I am facing very weird issue from the backend of paid membership pro when I try to export the Member list from export to CSV button. I can see the file but all fields are empty  [image: My CSV output]

**Note:**

There is no customization done for backend.

**List of plugin for export and import i have used** 
Paid Memberships Pro, Version 1.8.6.7
Paid Memberships Pro – Add Member Admin, Version .1
Paid Memberships Pro – Email Templates Add On, Version .5.5
Paid Memberships Pro – Member Homepages Add On, Version .1
Paid Memberships Pro – Register Helper Add On, Version 1.3.4
Paid Memberships Pro – WooCommerce Add On, Version 1.4
PMPro Customizations, Version .1

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the plugin already? Since it's a paid plugin, I'm guessing they must have a Support channel where they can help you out.

Comment: yes i have already add ticket